# Kolmogorov-Smirnov inconsistency with increasing dataset sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I want to compare two arbitrary distributions and know that Kolmogorov-Smirnov is one such test that can handle any non-normal distribution.

I noticed however, that p-values returned by the KS test are increasingly hard to interpret as dataset size increases.

To demonstrate, I created sample distributions using `np.random.normal()` and `np.random.random()` and computed the two-sample KS test p-values for various different datasets

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
np.random.seed(42)

# First example: data1 with 100 observations, data2 with 50 observations
N = 100

data1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
data2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1+np.random.rand()/1000, int(N/2)) + np.random.random()/100

plt.hist(data1, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.hist(data2, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.show()

_, ks_pval = ks_2samp(data1, data2)
print("p-value =", ks_pval)
```

KS returns a p-value of 0.80, showing thus quite a high confidence that the two distributions might come from the same distributions; despite the plot showing fairly different distributions:
[image]

```
# Second example: data1 with 1000 observations, data2 with 500 observations

N = 1000

data1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
data2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1+np.random.rand()/1000, int(N/2)) + np.random.random()/100

plt.hist(data1, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.hist(data2, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.show()

_, ks_pval = ks_2samp(data1, data2)
print("p-value =", ks_pval)
```

Increasing dataset sizes by a factor of ten yields visually much more similar plots, yet p-value returned by KS test has dropped to 0.37. Still significant, but seemingly KS test is much less certain about the two distributions coming from the same underlying distributions, despite visually the plots definitely seeming much more related.
[image]

```
# Third example: data1 with 10000 observations, data2 with 5000 observations

N = 10000

data1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
data2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1+np.random.rand()/1000, int(N/2)) + np.random.random()/100

plt.hist(data1, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.hist(data2, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.show()

_, ks_pval = ks_2samp(data1, data2)
print("p-value =", ks_pval)
```

This time two histograms are highly similar, yet KS test returned a p-value far in the insignificance range: a mere 0.0003.

[image]

```
# Fourth example: data1 with 100000 observations, data2 with 50000 observations

N = 100000

data1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, N)
data2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1+np.random.rand()/1000, int(N/2)) + np.random.random()/100

plt.hist(data1, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.hist(data2, alpha=0.3, bins=50)
plt.show()

_, ks_pval = ks_2samp(data1, data2)
print("p-value =", ks_pval)
```

Pattern is same; two plots look nearly perfect bell curves, yet KS test returns a p-value in the order of 1e-26.
[image]

I know about two alternatives to Kolmogorov-Smirnov, these being:

- Cramer-von Mises test
- Anderson-Darling test

I experimented with those as well, and findings are the same: the larger the datasets, the lower the confidence that they come from the same distribution.

Clearly I am misinterpreting something about statistical tests for comparing distributions, so I'd like to ask:

- How come KS test returned so high confidence in the first scenario despite difference between the two distributions having been so large?
- How come KS test returns near-zero confidence for near-identical distributions such as in the last case?
- And most importantly: **What would be the preferred technique to reliably compare *large* non-normally distributed datasets?**

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! `data1` and `data2` are different distributions, right?

Comment: @Dave thank you! Sorry about the earlier incorrect comment! 
`data1` and `data2` are to represent distributions of training, test, validation data over time. Data for one week and another week must be compared before training/testing to ensure no data drift is present. So `data1` can be for instance training data of last week, and `data2` training data of this week.

Comment: In your simulation, `data1` and `data2` have different distributions, right?